# xmllint shell not showing number from count xpath expression?

Tags: xmllint

I am using xmllint's interactive shell on cygwin. I would like to count the number of nodes, but xmllint doesn't seem to behaving as I expect:

```
$> cat test.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>
  <node>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </node>
</result>
$> xmllint --shell test.xml
/ > cat count(/result/node/item)
count(/result/node/item) is a number
```

It says it's a number, but it doesn't show the number in a manner I've seen from web searches:

```
count(/result/node/item) is a number : 5
```

What is going wrong here?

```
$> xmllint --version
xmllint: using libxml version 20706
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib
```

Comment: Try `xpath` instead of `cat`

Comment: Darn, I found xpath examples here: http://lizards.opensuse.org/2009/11/23/playing-with-xpath-expressions-in-the-xmllint-shell/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I realize @Stephane mentioned this in the comments but I came across this technique and was going to post this answer prior to seeing his comment with the same solution. Not sure of the etiquette for this, but here's what I found. LMK and I can delete this answer if it's inappropriate to post an answer on someone else's comment.

#### Solution

You need to use the `xpath` command within xmllint to display the result being returned from the `count` function.

```
$ xmllint --shell test.xml 
/ > cat         
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<result>
  <node>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </node>
</result>

/ > xpath count(/result/node/item)
Object is a number : 5
/ >
```

Found the answer here on this site: [Playing With XPath Expressions in The xmllint Shell](http://lizards.opensuse.org/2009/11/23/playing-with-xpath-expressions-in-the-xmllint-shell/).